# Possible sources for a sliver of metal found embedded into a resin print?

Tags: maintenance

I have an Elegoo Saturn and have just completed a print using standard Elegoo gray resin. I saw what I though was the remains of a failed support sticking out of my print but upon looking closer it is a sliver of metal swarf approximately 5-6mm long and 1/2mm wide. It looked "visually similar" to drill swarf from aluminium or low grade stainless. It was incorporated into the side of the model rather than sitting on the surface.

I have checked my build plate and the metal scraper that I use to remove models from the plate (Still in the draw so not used in over a week) but wasn't able to find any damage to either so they are unlikely sources, the sliver is of such a size that I should easily be able to see damage to one of the other (My FEP is undamaged, which was a relief).

The metal was silver in color and so is unlikely to have come from my Vat.

I keep the plastic cover on my printer at all times except when I'm preparing it for a print, removing a print or cleaning it, so it is not likely to have pinged in from elsewhere. I don't do metal crafts at all, so it isn't contamination from another project that I've been doing.

I have considered that I may have received a contaminated batch of resin. I'm near the bottom of the bottle so it's plausible that it could have been in there.

Is this something that is known to happen with this model of printer or with Elegoo printers in general, and are there any other likely sources for a sliver of silver colored metal where I could look for damage?

Comment: That's pretty strange! I'd recommend filtering the rest of the resin, and storing it in a separate resin bottle (or wash out the existing one with IPA to make sure no residue remains, just in case)